# Materials to learn how to model using ODEs and PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

could someone please share any material that I could use to learn how to model problems using difference equations,ODEs and PDEs, I'm taking a course in Mathematical modeling but we hardly learn techniques on how to model a problem, its mainly how to solve PDEs, the only model I recall use doing was SIR and fluid mechanics :(, I've read a book on Computational Neuroscience, i understand the ODE models and the modelling process, but then again its a bit high level

Answer (score 0):

My lecture notes on differential equations is maybe too low level, but emphasizes applications, see http://bterrell.net

Comment: i had a quick look this is exactly what I need, thank you